# Handling Null issue with .split method & JOP.InputDialog Java

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

So this is a snippet of code for a uni project im doing fairly new to java so excuse any poor code. One of the restrictions is that the code mustn't have errors on exit / cancel. So i understand that the cancel button on JOptionPane.showInputDialog returns null but it seems the section of 'parts = temp.split(" ")' is for reasons unknown to me blocking input from being null? When i get rid of parts=temp.split() there is no exception thrown when cancel button is selected but then obviously the for loop doesn't work.So what i need to do is for there to be no exception or error's produced upon cancel.Any help would be appreciated! :)
** Edit** We're also forbidden to use catch, try or break any while loops.Must exit with a true / false.

```
    while (X == true && flag == true) {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tell me more about " + topics[z]);
        String temp = input;
        if (input != null) {
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (input == null) {
            flag = false;
        }

        parts = temp.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < topics.length; x++) {
                if (parts[i].equals(topics[x])) {
                    cut = parts[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
            if (cut.equals(topics[i])) {
                z = i;
                break;
            }

        }

        input = cut;
        System.out.print(cut);
        System.out.println(z);

        X = Arrays.asList(topics[z]).contains(input);
        System.out.println(X);

    }
```

Comment: what do you want when cancel button is clicked?

Comment: Im getting this in my eclipse console  : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at AMRGst2.main(AMRGst2.java:62) and im required to have no errors or red basically in my console upon cancel

Comment: You need to write `parts = temp.split(" ");` inside `if (input != null)` and make sure `parts` is initialized before this as well; otherwise you'll get `NPE` in line `parts.length` as well

Comment: Yes!! Thanks heaps, that has worked :) Funny how once you see the solution it seems so obvious haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `parts = temp.split(" ");` inside `if (input != null)` and make sure `parts` is initialized before this as well; otherwise you'll get `NPE` in line `parts.length` as well. 
I'll assume `topics` is not null:

```
while (X == true && flag == true) {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tell me more about " + topics[z]);
        String temp = input;
        parts = new String[initialArraySize];

        if (input != null) {
            parts = temp.split(" ");
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (input == null) {
            flag = false;
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < topics.length; x++) {
                if (parts[i].equals(topics[x])) {
                    cut = parts[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
            if (cut.equals(topics[i])) {
                z = i;
                break;
            }

        }

        input = cut;
        System.out.print(cut);
        System.out.println(z);

        X = Arrays.asList(topics[z]).contains(input);
        System.out.println(X);

    }
```